# The suffix -говорящий

Tags: суффиксы, приставки

I would like to convey a rather complex idea in Russian.

Switzerland is a multilingual country where, among other languages, French and German are spoken.

However, there are more german-speaking Swiss who know French than french-speaking Swiss who know German, and I would like to tell exactly this in Russian.

I know the words **англоговорящий** and **русскоговорящий**. But I doubt just every language can be attached to this suffix (plus англо- and русско- are themselves adaptations into a prefix, and I don't know if every language has a prefix of its own).

1. First, the sentence I am looking for. Does it work like this?

> Есть больше немецкоговорящих швейцарцев, знающих французский, чем 
>   французскоговорящих  швейцарцев, знающих немецкий.

Again, I'm not sure about the language prefixes. Maybe I could use "немецкие швейцарцы" and "французские швейцарцы" instead?

2. Which are the language prefixes for the following languages?
   итальянский, португальский, испанский, японский.

Comment: @Alex_ander got it completely right - `англоворящий` is somebody who knows English to some decent extent, `англоязычный` is native English speaker.

Comment: i agree with Alex_ander's phrasing (regardless of the words choice)  ***Немецкоговорящих швейцарцев, знающих французский, больше, чем франкоговорящих швейцарцев, знающих немецкий***, as usage of ***есть*** in place of English there's/re isn't typical to Russian

Comment: A note: `-говорящий` is not a siffix, but a part of a compound word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. Немецкоязычных швейцарцев, знающих французский, больше, чем франкоязычных (швейцарцев), знающих немецкий.

2. It's possible to find in a modern 'synonyms' dictionary (e.g. Тришин, 2013) versions like: **немецкоговорящий (германоговорящий), франкоговорящий (also, noun: франкофон), италоговорящий, португалоговорящий, испаноговорящий, японоговорящий**. All of those (presumably, coming from the form like 'English speaker') have *older*, more traditional versions, ending with **-язычный**. The version like **англоговорящий** is not always applied to a native speaker, it sometimes describes a technician with language training (*англоговорящий технический специалист*) for working abroad, etc.

Comment: Yes, **-язычный** implies a first language whereas **-говорящий** can refer to any level of command of the spoken language.

Answer (score 1):

Just like it was already mentioned for `франкоговорящие`/`франкоязычные` there's relatively widely known and accepted [`франкофон`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B). Actually there's less known and less used however existing term [`лузофон`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B) for one who talks Portuguese.

There are also [`англофоны`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B), `синофоны` (for Chinese speakers) and even [`румынофоны`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) however this terms are used extremely rare. One just can not add `-фон` to some derivative of language name, it doesn't work that way.

In some texts that tend to sound as scientific and official as possible one can even find `германофон` but that's definitely rather a curiosity.